# Scope of parameter names in Objective C methods

Tags: objective-c, scope

```
// myClass.h
@interface myClass : NSObject {
    int variable1;
}

- (int) addOne: (int)variable1;

//myClass.m
- (int) addOne: (int)variable1{
variable1++;
}
```

My question is: will `[myClass addOne:aNumber]` add 1 to `aNumber` or will it add 1 to the value of the ivar `variable1`?

Comment: One more question: is common convention to just make your function parameters have a unique name or will I see the above situation often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variable (or function parameter) hides instance variable declaration (you should get compiler warning about that) - so **local copy** of aNumber will be incremented.

Comment: Quick response and very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will add one to aNumber in order to add one to ivar you will have to write self.variable1 += 1, I think even ++ may work.

Comment: you will need to declare a property for variable1 to use that. self->variable1+=1 will work as well.

Comment: yeh you are right, I am not objective-c expert, i thought self.variable must do it, but yes it should be self->variable, thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you literally mean that `self->variable` will give you the ivar without having to declare a property for it?

Comment: @GP, yes, self->variable will give you the ivar without having to declare property in its own class, however i dont know if objective-c has access restrictions like public or private, otherwise you can access it from anywhere, i think its like C, you can access anywhere.